# JetBrains Rider new bash terminal in working directory on Windows with WSL

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rider

Using JetBrains Rider an Windows 10 with Ubuntu in the WSL.

When i use the Windows cmd.exe as shell path for the integrated terminal in Rider im starting in the current directory of the open solution/folder.

If i use ubuntu2004 as shell path i start a bash. But the directory is always home/"Username". And i have to change it manually.

Is there a way to start the terminal/bash with the current directory.

Comment: Not sure about rider, but intellij has the option "Start Directory" in terminal settings. Works for me for wsl.exe as default terminal. Else there are some plugins like openTerminalHere which might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "wsl.exe" as shell path let the terminal start in the current directory.